# Trying to use DataSource for migrations setup and getting error `Cannot use import statement outside a module`

Tags: typescript, nestjs, typeorm

I'm trying to setup migrations config in my `nestjs` app with `typeorm`. Currently I'm getting error when trying to start app by running the script `yarn start:dev`.

```
import { DataSource } from 'typeorm';
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

My DataSource config looks like:

```
import { DataSource } from 'typeorm';
import * as dotenv from 'dotenv';

dotenv.config();

const config = new DataSource({
  type: 'postgres',
  host: process.env.POSTGRES_HOST,
  port: Number(process.env.POSTGRES_PORT),
  username: process.env.POSTGRES_USER,
  password: process.env.POSTGRES_PASSWORD,
  database: process.env.POSTGRES_DB,
  migrations: [__dirname + '/../*.js', __dirname + '/../*/*.js'],
  migrationsTableName: 'migration',
});

export default config;
```

And the path in my app to this file is `src/migration/config/ormConfig.ts`. Also in `src/migration` I got all my migrations and some of them inside folders - `src/migration/someFolder/someMigration.js` and so on. Why am I getting such error? And how can I run my app without this error?
In my package.json - `"ts-node": "^10.9.1", "typeorm": "^0.3.17", "typescript": "^5.2.2"`
The interesting thing is - if I run migration using the script `yarn migrate:run: "./node_modules/.bin/ts-node ./node_modules/.bin/typeorm migration:run -d src/migration/config/ormConfig"` it will run succesfully.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ty_Zs2w3KYo